Как проверить SAS диски с помощью MHDD?
Все поиски в поисковике привели к тому, что вроде бы есть какие-то контроллеры, которые "видит" MHDD. У меня есть LSI-9211 - его не видит (MHDD v. 4.6). Может быть кто-то сталкивался и может подсказать конкретную модель?

нужно перевести контроллёр в режим IDE
